# File upload in ionic (image or any file)?

Tags: ionic-framework

can any one please sort it out it gives error `FileTransfer is not defined`.

Below is my code

```
controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

     $scope.upload = function() {
        var options = {
            fileKey: "avatar",
            fileName: "yedu.jpg",
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "image/jpg"
        };
        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("http://192.168.1.109/uploads/upload", "/android_asset/www/img/yedu.jpg", options).then(function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
            // constant progress updates
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in the browser? If so, you're not going to have access to Cordova plugins until it is launched as an app on a device/emulator.

Comment: k i got it ,it means plugin is not supported for browser.

Comment: It's not that the plugin isn't supported in the browser, it's that Cordova is meant to give you an interface to native device features. The browser on your computer isn't one of those devices. Cordova/PhoneGap isn't meant for the browser at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you getting error in browser . As per the official documentation of plugin this plugin is not supported to browser for more details go to [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) and [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/).

If you testing in browser then before installing app in device add the cordovaFileTransfer plugin to your project.

```
      cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

And for the full implementation of file upload and download with cordova you may go to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html).